# Find the sum of an entire matrix using functions (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, matrix

I am writing some code that writes a matrix with a 10x10 size and prints it using functions. What I need is a function that takes the sum of the entire matrix array. What I have done is that I tried to sum up each row and column separately and add the total together. The problem with mine is that I believe that it only prints out the sum of the row or the column.

This is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int ROW_SIZE = 10;
const int COLUMN_SIZE = 10;

void initialize(int [][10], int, int);
void display(int matrix[][10], int, int);
void sum(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int, int);

int main() {

    int matrix [ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];

    initialize(matrix, ROW_SIZE, COLUMN_SIZE);

    display(matrix, ROW_SIZE,COLUMN_SIZE);

    sum(matrix, ROW_SIZE,COLUMN_SIZE);


    return 0;
}



void initialize(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            matrix[i][j] =  1 + rand() % 99;
        }
    }
}


void display(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            cout<< setw(4)<<matrix[i][j]<< " ";
        }
         cout<< endl;
    }
}


void sum(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    int sum_row;
    int sum_col;

    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        int sum_row = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            sum_row = sum_row + matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        int sum_col = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            sum_col = sum_col + matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    int sum = sum_row + sum_col;

    cout<<"The sum of the matrix is "<<sum<< endl;
}
```

Comment: Your `sum` function should have a for similar to the `display` function and just every element to a total sum. Alternatively, you can use the `std::accumulate()` standard algorithm to do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is sum of last row + last column. This should be enough:

```
void sum(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            sum += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"The sum of the matrix is "<<sum<< endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

few early problems in your code

```
void sum(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    int sum_row; // uninitialized make it equal to 0
    int sum_col; // uninitialized make it equal to 0

    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        int sum_row = 0; // This is local to block and masks the sum_row above
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            sum_row = sum_row + matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        int sum_col = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            sum_col = sum_col + matrix[i][j]; //Iterating over rows again matrix[j][i] may be
        }
    }

    int sum = sum_row + sum_col;

    cout<<"The sum of the matrix is "<<sum<< endl;
}
```

---

```
void sum(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    int sum_row = 0;
    int sum_col = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++)
            sum_row += matrix[i][j];
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++)
            sum_col += matrix[j][i];
    
    int sum = sum_row + sum_col;
    cout<<"The sum of the matrix is "<<sum<< endl;
}
```

---

Now of course the question and logic doesn't seem to co-exist together and if `sum of entire matrix` means sum of all elements which is what it sounds like it can be achieved with the one here

```
void sum(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            sum += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<"The sum of the matrix is "<<sum<< endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something wrong in terms of naming. You have constants called `ROW_SIZE` and `COLUMN_SIZE` and then you have parameters with the same names to functions like `sum()`. This is confusing for something reading your code. Call your parameters something else, like `rows` and `columns`.

Here is an alternative to the proposed solutions using `std::accumulate()`.

```cpp
const int ROW_SIZE = 3;
const int COLUMN_SIZE = 3;

void sum(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int const rows, int const cols)
{
    int sum = std::accumulate(&matrix[0][0], &matrix[rows-1][cols], 0);    
    std::cout<<"The sum of the matrix is "<<sum<< std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int m[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE] {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
  sum(m, ROW_SIZE, COLUMN_SIZE);
}
```

`std::accumulate()` takes the iterators that delimit a range. Those are the iterators to the first element and the one past the last element of the range. In this case, these are `&matrix[0][0]` and `&matrix[row-1][col]` (since `&matrix[row-1][col-1]` is the last element of the matrix). There are other ways to put that, such as the following:

```cpp
auto begin = std::begin(matrix[0]);
int sum = std::accumulate(begin, begin + rows * cols, 0);
```